# View ipython notebook results (apache spark) as dashboard

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, ibm-cloud

I am currently working with a customer who has asked a dashboard showing analytics result on screen. The notebooks I create in apache spark can only be executed from Bluemix notebook editor. This is not business friendly. All samples I have seen on ibm bluemix apache spark talks about running ipython notebook from bluemix notebook editor.
Can you please advice if there is a way to expose and access a notebook using a dashboard so that business user only sees the fruits (charts and graphs) and it hides the underline notebook code.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is old, I would still want to answer, so that other people who ended up in a similar problem like yours and mine, may have a solution. So this can work out with Jupyter Dashboards a plugin for ipython notebook in jupyter.

http://jupyter-dashboards-layout.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html

The link is here for the documentation.

Another way could be, using zeppelin notebook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to show only the output without the code cells.

If you can wait until IBM's Data Science Experience at http://datascience.ibm.com/ goes public, there's a good chance that you'll find that feature there.